# Suddenly Can't connect to SSH server Error fetching database list Connection Population Error using Red Gate MySQL Compare Devart dotConnect for MySQL

Tags: mysql, ssh, connection, redgate, dotconnect

update 5/24/2017

sudo grep Kex /etc/ssh/sshd_config

**KexAlgorithms diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256**

**This is definitely enabled**.

end update 5/24/2017

Suddenly, can't connect to SSH server using [Red Gate's MySQL Compare and MySQL Data Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/mysql/mysql-comparison-bundle/) which were working well for several days. Suddenly I now get the below error message which I suspect is itself potentially misleading. I'm hoping someone may have seen this behavior before and suggest what I might do to solve.

Background:

1. I had previously been successfully using both MySQL Compare and MySQL Data Compare via their SSH user interface accessing databases residing on 2 separate domains/machines.
2. Now neither program can **connect to SSH server** on either of the machines and produce the error.

Clicking on Compare Now button produces . . .

MySQL Compare - Aborting
**Can't connect to SSH server** on 'xxxx.com':
**Server does not support diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 for keyexchange**

Additionally, MySQL Data Compare produces the below popup message . . .

Connection Population Error
Unknown exception: **Can't connect to SSH server** on 'xxxx.com':
Server does not support diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 for keyexchange

Clicking on the Database button to populate the drop-down list produces . . .

Error fetching database list
Error connecting to database
**Can't connect to SSH server** on 'xxxx.com':
Server does not support diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256 for keyexchange

The connection is managed using a third-party component from another company named Devart ([according to this source](https://forum.red-gate.com/discussion/19848/ssh-based-connection-fails) and confirmed here by Brian Donahue at Red Gate that it is Devart's dotConnect for MySQL https:// forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=29052&p=99554#p99554 ).

I'm hoping someone may have seen this behavior before and suggest what I might do to solve.